# Finding the number of balls in an urn from the probability of it being chosen

Tags: probability, probability-theory

An urn contains $4$ green balls and $6$ blue balls. A second urn contains $16$ green and $N$ blue balls. A single ball is drawn at random from each urn. The probability that both balls are of the same colour is $0.58$. Find $N$.

**My progress so far:**
We know that choosing balls of the same colour is the union fo the two disjoint events of choosing two green or two blue balls. So we simply need to find the probability of each of those events and then we are finished.

However, we don't know how to find the probability of the second balls chosen being either green or blue, as we don't know $N$, so how could I calculate that?

Comment: I would break it down into four conditional outcomes: You picked two greens, two blues, green from 1st and blue from 2nd, and blue from 1st and green from 2nd.  Since all four outcomes together combine to give probability 1, you should add them all up (you'll get some function of N) and solve for 1.

Comment: Try using $N$ as a variable and write down the equation for the probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of both balls being green is:

$P(bothGreen) = \frac{4}{4+6}*\frac{16}{16+N}$

The probability of both balls being blue is:

$P(bothBlue) = \frac{6}{4+6}*\frac{N}{16+N}$

And you know that $P(bothGreen) + P(bothBlue) = 0.58$, so you just need to solve the equation:

$\frac{4}{10}*\frac{16}{16+N} + \frac{6}{10}*\frac{N}{16+N} = 0.58$